# Jenkins: Add build step doesn't work

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, http-status-code-404, jenkins-plugins

I have a strange error that I am not able to add anything in build step or post build action in my jenkins.

I get the following error when I inspect the same.

> Error 404 Not Found
>
> ### HTTP ERROR 404
>
> Problem accessing
>   /$stapler/bound/5a0d5381-ed63-4616-8dcb-bbc1edac79b3/render. Reason:
>
> ```
>     Not Found
> ```
>
> ---
>
> *Powered by
>   Jetty://*

I have tried the following,

1. Clearing browser data, updating firefox version from 30.0 to 34.0
2. Upgrading jenkins
3. Restarting it
4. Manually try to edit config.xml to add build step.
5. Creating the new job also has the same issue. Clicking on the add build steps does nothing. Inspecting for errors gives me the above error. Couldn't enable stapler logging also.

Nothing is successful. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, it's unlikely that SO will be able to troubleshoot your system. Check the jenkins logs on the host server. Rollback recent changes made to the Jenkins installation.

Comment: Are you facing the issue with only one particular job or all of them?